# Simple C program won't return square of number

Tags: c

Super basic C program from textbook.

Want to return square of `valA`.

```
int squarer(int valA) {
    return valA * valA;
 }

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int valA = 5;
    squarer(valA);
    printf("\"%d\" squared is \"%d\".\n", valA, squarer);
    return 0;
 }
```

Code prints `"5" squared is "3824".` to console.

Comment: also, just curious, but why 3824?

Comment: Compiler warning: "warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int (*)(int)'"

Comment: 3824 because that's the address of the `squarer` function when printed as an `int`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just printed the **address** of the `squarer` function. If you compile with warnings enabled (`-Wall` or similar), the compiler will tell you this.

The result from calling `squarer` isn't stored anywhere: you just threw it out.

If you write

```
int result = squarer(valA);
printf("\"%d\" squared is \"%d\".\n", valA, result);
```

you will see the right answer.

Comment: The print statement is **UB**.

Comment: @Deduplicator In what way is it UB?

Comment: @CareyGregory: Printing a value with the wrong format code is UB.

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm sure the OP used "..." to indicate "whatever format you choose" and didn't expect anyone to take it literally.